# 1 final compiler error :( can someone explain in real simple for me

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, linear-algebra, calculator

> C:\Users\George\Desktop\linear_equation_calc\main.cpp||In function
>   'int main(int, const char**)':|
>   C:\Users\George\Desktop\linear_equation_calc\main.cpp|101|error:
>   'calcparallelplugin' was not declared in this scope| 
>   ||=== Build finished: 1 errors, 0 warnings ===|

this is the error that i keep getting. i understand what declaring means but i jsut really dont understand how im supposed to declare it as im using the calcparallelplugin() to link in another .cpp file. i know its not standard practice to have seperate .cpp files and not headers. Someone explain in really simple terms please, i am as thick as s*** at the moment

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

// Function includes
// I try to keep them in the order they appear in the
// output below for organization purposes
#include "calc.m.xy12plugin.cpp"
#include "calc.b.xymplugin.cpp"
#include "calc.m.xybplugin.cpp"
#include "calc.point.xymplugin.cpp"
#include "calc.parallelplugin.cpp"

// The above one would be here, too

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
  int i;
  i = 0;
  cout << "Linear Equation Calculator" << endl << "Copyright (c) 2011 Patrick Devaney" << endl
  << "Licensed under the Apache License Version 2" << endl;
  // This loop makes the code a bit messy,
  // but it's worth it so the program doesn't
  // crash if one enters random crap such as
  // "zrgxvd" or "54336564358"
  while(i < 1) {
    cout << "Type:" << endl
    << "0 to calculate a slope (the M value) based on two points on a line" << endl
    << "1 to calculate the Y-intercept (the B value) based on two points and a slope" << endl
    << "2 to calculate the slope (the M value) based on the Y-intercept and X and Y" << endl <<
    "plug-ins" << endl
    << "3 to find the next point up or down a line based on the slope (M) and X and Y"
    << endl << "plug-ins" << endl
    << "4 to find a point x positions down the line based on the slope (M) and X and Y"
    << endl << "plug-ins" << endl
    << "5 to find the equation of a parallel line in form y=mx+c"
    << endl << "plug-ins" << endl;

    string selection;
    cin >> selection;
    if(selection == "0") {
      mcalcxyplugin();
      i++;
    }
    else if(selection == "1") {
      calcbxymplugin();
      i++;
    }
    else if(selection == "2") {
      calcmxybplugin();
      i++;
    }
    else if(selection == "3") {
      calcpointxymplugin(1);
      i++;
    }
    else if(selection == "4") {
      int a;
      cout << "How many points up/down the line do you want? (Positive number for points" << endl
      << "further up, negative for previous points" << endl;
      cin >> a;
      calcpointxymplugin(a);
      i++;
    }
    else if(selection == "5"){

      calcparallelplugin();
      i++;
    }
    else {
      i = 1;
    }
    // End of that loop below
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1. seriously - fix your code so that the _code_ is in `.cpp` files, and the declarations in `.h` files.  2.  how can we know why your function is apparently undeclared if you don't show that part of the source!

Comment: This is attacking my eyes, please format your code!!! You should really define your interfaces to your methods in header files and include the header files not the cpp files which are the implementation details

Comment: @Alnitak 3. Accept more answers!

Answer (score 3):

Error not declared in this scope means exactly that. After all the `#include<...>` files have been included in your main file, the compiler couldn't find that function, so it doesn't know what to do.

However, this also applies to another case:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    testfunc();
}

void testfunc()
{
    std::cout << "test!" << std::endl;
}
```

In this case, the reason for the problem is that the compiler needs functions to be forward-declared - i.e. it needs function prototypes. This will work:

```
#include <iostream>

void testfunc(); // the compiler sees this and knows the linker
                 // has the responsibility of finding this symbol.

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    testfunc();
}

void testfunc()
{
    std::cout << "test!" << std::endl;
}
```

There's another case with regards to scoping, too. Namespaces affect scope, so for example:

```
#include <iostream>

void testfunc();

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    testfunc();
}

namespace test
{
    void testfunc()
    {
        std::cout << "test!" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Will also fail. For your prototype, you need `void test::testfunc();`. This is because the inside of the namespace is a scope in its own right, as opposed to the global scope `::`. By writing `using namespace std;` in your code, you're making functions available in `std` available in the global namespace.

I also notice you used `.cpp` for your includes. The convention is to use `.h` or `.hpp` for header files, which often comprise forward declarations, classes etc for a corresponding `.cpp` implementation.

So, I would check that:

- The code isn't namespace'd.
- You're including the right thing.
- You are calling the function with the right name.